# How do I create an apparmor profile for an application that runs using Python's twisted library?

Tags: python, security, twisted, apparmor

I'm trying to create an apparmor profile for a networking application with access to ssh and runs using Python's twisted library. I have tried using aa-genprof to generate a profile. In another bash, I ran my applications with a few test cases. However, no rules are being generated. How do I go about generating the profile?